# Passing the return value of a method, to another method as an argument, inside of a seperate method

Tags: c++, methods

This is more simple than it sounds I promise. I've checked other posts, but I have not successfully found anything yet.

I have a method `AList::GenerateRandom()`:

```
void AList::GenerateRandom(){
    int randomAmount;
    int randomLimitHigh;
    srand(int(time(0)));

    cout << "\nResetting the current list using randomly generated elements.\n\n";
    cout << "Enter the desired number of elements (0 to 50): " ;
    randomAmount = ReadRandomAmount();
    randomLimitLow = ReadRandomLimitLow();
    randomLimitHigh = ReadRandomLimitHigh(randomLimitLow);

    cout << "\n\nFinished resetting, " << randomAmount << "elements between" <<  randomLimitLow << " and " << randomLimitHigh << "randomly generated.\n\n";
  }
```

It was all working out fine until I decided it would be best to include the value of randomLimitLow.

Now I'm getting this ambiguous error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "AList::ReadRandomAmount()", referenced from:
      AList::GenerateRandom() in AList-2fa708.o
  "AList::ReadRandomLimitLow()", referenced from:
      AList::GenerateRandom() in AList-2fa708.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Here is the contents of the other methods

```
int ReadRandomAmount(){
        int randomAmount;        // used to collect the user's input
        cin >> boolalpha >> randomAmount;

        while (! cin.good() || randomAmount < 0 || randomAmount > 50) {

                cin.clear();

                cin.ignore(80, '\n');

               if(!cin.good()){
                  cout << "Invalid data type, should be an element ("
                        << ELEMENT_NAME
                        << "), try again: ";
                  } else
                  cout << "Invalid range type, should be within 0 and 50, try again: ";

                cin >> boolalpha >> randomAmount;
                }

        return randomAmount;
    }

  int ReadRandomLimitLow(){
        int randomLimitLow;        // used to collect the user's input

        cin >> boolalpha >> randomLimitLow;

        while (! cin.good() || randomLimitLow < 0 || randomLimitLow > 2147483646) {

                cin.clear();

                cin.ignore(80, '\n');

               if(!cin.good()){
                  cout << "Invalid data type, should be an element ("
                        << ELEMENT_NAME
                        << "), try again: ";
                  } else
                  cout << "Invalid range type, should be within 0 and 2147483646, try again: ";

                cin >> boolalpha >> randomLimitLow;
                }

        return randomLimitLow;
    }

  int ReadRandomLimitHigh(int randomLimitLow){
        int randomLimitHigh;        // used to collect the user's input

        cin >> boolalpha >> randomLimitHigh;


        while (! cin.good() || randomLimitHigh < randomLimitLow || randomLimitHigh > 2147483647) {


                cin.clear();


                cin.ignore(80, '\n');


               if(!cin.good()){
                  cout << "Invalid data type, should be an element ("
                        << ELEMENT_NAME
                        << "), try again: ";
                  } else
                  cout << "Invalid range type, should be within " << randomLimitLow << " and 2147483647, try again: ";

                cin >> boolalpha >> randomLimitHigh;
                }

        return randomLimitHigh;
    }
```

How do I insure that `ReadRandomLimitHigh()` will only take a value that is greater than the value of `ReadRandomLimitLow()`

Comment: At least in the code you posted, `randomLimitLow` is never declared. Does declaring it as an `int` help?

Comment: Step 1: don't use `srand`/`rand` - you'll get horrifically bad random numbers. Please see [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: Do you declare `ReadRandomAmount()` in the `AList` class definition? You seem to have it as a global function.

Comment: I didn't post the definitions but yes they're all in there, were working fine too until I tried to include the return value of ReadRandomLimitLow as a argument

Comment: Dammit, your crystal ball is right...

Comment: n.m. put something in the main thread and the credit is yours.

Comment: Your braces are all wrong too. Stick to consistent indentation and that all becomes much more obvious. I also find also find it much easier to spot missing braces when you put the opening brace on the next line....many will disagree though!

Comment: I tried to put them in a file, added some declarations and it compiles without errors. Can you post your class declaration here?